# hg serve simply hangs in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial

I've started using Mercurial for my personal projects and I'm currently going through Joel's tutorial here: http://hginit.com/02.html

The problem is when I type in `hg serve` in the terminal, it simply hangs. Other commands like `hg init` works perfectly. Anyone know what's going on?

I installed mercurial by doing this: `sudo apt-get install mercurial meld`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use the -d option to run it in the background:

```
hg serve -d
```

Otherwise it will just run as a foreground process, logging to stdout and stderr.

Run `hg help serve` to see more options.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the port to something other than 8000, like `hg serve -p 9001`.  Could be a conflict.  Also note that when it runs, it doesn't print anything out to the terminal.  It just sits there until you `CTRL+C` out of it.